# Why am I getting ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint? Missing index for constraint XXXX in the referenced table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Why am I keep getting the following error while creating tables?

> ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint.  Missing
> index for constraint
> 'fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT1' in the
> referenced table 'PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT'

I defined the primary keyset of PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT table as the foreign key in PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX table.

If I dropped  STOREFRONT`and` TENANT` as FOREIGN KEY in PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX then it's working.

What am I missing?

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD` (
  `PAYMENT_METHODID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHODID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT = Default;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT` (
  `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `TENANT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `MODIFY_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT_PAYMENT_METHOD1_idx` (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`, `TENANT`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT_PAYMENT_METHOD1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD` (`PAYMENT_METHODID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT` (
  `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `TENANT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `STOREFRONT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `MODIFY_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`, `TENANT`, `STOREFRONT`),
  INDEX `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT1_idx` (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` ASC, `TENANT` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT` (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX` (
  `PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `TENANT` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `STOREFRONT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DISP_ORDER` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `MODIFY_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_ID`, `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`, `TENANT`, `STOREFRONT`, `COUNTRY`),
  INDEX `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT1_idx` (`STOREFRONT` ASC, `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` ASC, `TENANT` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`STOREFRONT` , `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT` (`STOREFRONT` , `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: 1) The expression in referenced table must be a key. 2) You cannot create key which contains some column twice. Resume: use synthetic, not natural, primary key(s), refer by them.

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `STOREFRONT` ASC in index `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT1_idx`
of `PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX` table. This fixed the issue. But though it's working I would suggest you to use same length of Varchar for TENANT column to avoid any further problem in those two tables.

```
Working Code:
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PAYMENT_METHOD (
>   `PAYMENT_METHODID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHODID`))
> ENGINE = InnoDB
> ROW_FORMAT = Default;
>
>
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> -- Table `PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT`
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT` (
>   `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `TENANT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>   `MODIFY_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>   INDEX `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT_PAYMENT_METHOD1_idx` (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`, `TENANT`),
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT_PAYMENT_METHOD1`
>     FOREIGN KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`)
>     REFERENCES `PAYMENT_METHOD` (`PAYMENT_METHODID`)
>     ON DELETE NO ACTION
>     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> -- Table `PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT`
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT` (
>   `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `TENANT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `STOREFRONT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>   `MODIFY_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`, `TENANT`, `STOREFRONT`),
>   INDEX `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT1_idx` (`STOREFRONT` ASC,`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`  ASC, `TENANT` ASC) VISIBLE,
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENANT1`
>     FOREIGN KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
>     REFERENCES `PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT` (`PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
>     ON DELETE NO ACTION
>     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> -- Table `PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX`
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX` (
>   `PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_ID` INT NOT NULL,
>   `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `TENANT` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   `STOREFRONT` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `COUNTRY` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   `DISP_ORDER` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
>   `STATUS` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
>   `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>   `MODIFY_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_ID`, `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID`, `TENANT`, `STOREFRONT`, `COUNTRY`),
>   INDEX `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT1_idx` (`STOREFRONT` ASC, `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` ASC, `TENANT` ASC) VISIBLE,
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_PAYMENT_METHOD_MATRIX_PAYMENT_METHOD_TENT_STRFRNT1`
>     FOREIGN KEY (`STOREFRONT` , `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
>     REFERENCES `PAYMENT_METHOD_TNANT_STRFRNT` (`STOREFRONT` , `PAYMENT_METHOD_ID` , `TENANT`)
>     ON DELETE NO ACTION
>     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67ae3cff6be0e51d59289b0155cdec35)*

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: @VijayKumarRajput Problem has been resolved. Please check my revised answer.